# Laravel Queue Daemon Worker on Red Hat Enterprise 6.7 via Upstart

Tags: linux, laravel-5, queue, redhat

I created a file called testjob.conf in /etc/init/testjob.conf with the following code:

```
start on runlevel [2345]
exec /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/appname/artisan queue:work --daemon
exec echo The Laravel Queue Listener successfully started as daemon process at `date` >> /var/log/testjob.log
```

The path to the laravel app is correct, and the path to php should also be correct. Confirmed with:

```
$php --version
```

Returning:

```
$php: /usr/bin/php /etc/php.ini /etc/php.d /usr/lib64/php     /usr/share/php /usr/share/man/man1/php.1.gz
```

On reboot the log file gets written to confirming that the UpStart service is working. The problem is that queue worker is not working. Anyone else out there trying to get a laravel queue to automatically work on system reboot without using any other packages such as supervisor? Tips are appreciated.